# STUCK! Validation with integers, character to integer conversion, ASCII and MIDI

Tags: c++

Ok so my C++ knowledge is so little, i've been slowly piecing together a code but in all honesty i'm surprised i've got this far.

Just to outline my task. The user is asked to enter in several notes (musical notes, C-B including Sharps, across 9 octaves) to create a melody line and then again but a bass line. After a note has been entered, a note length must also be

```
#‎include‬ <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int notenumber;
struct noteStorage
{
string noteName;
int midiNumber;
int noteLength;
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//VALIDATION FOR NOTE NAME
bool ValidateNote(string note)
{
// Step 1: If note name length is less than 2 OR more than 3, return false
if (note.length() <2 || note.length() >3) 
{
cout<<"Note length must be 2 or 3 characters\n";
return false;
}
//Step 2: If true, the note must be/(or be) between A and G
else if(tolower(note[0])<'a' || tolower(note[0]) >'g') 
{
cout<<"Note must be A-G\n";
return false;
}
//Step 3: If true, the last character must be a digit
else if(isdigit(note[note.length()-1]) == false)
{
cout<<"Last character must be a digit\n";
return false;
}
//Step 4: If note length is 3 note[1] (character 2) must be '#'.
else if(note.length() == 3 && note[1] != '#')
{
"Invalid sharp note\n";
return false;
}
return true;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//VALIDATION FOR NOTE LENGTH
bool ValidateNoteLength (int length)
//Step 1 - If notelength is not a digit, return FALSE
{
if (length == false)
{
cout<<"Note length must be a digit/number, please re-enter";
return false;
}
//Step 2 - If notelength is less than or equal to 0 or more than 16, return FALSE
if (length <= 0 || length > 16)
{
cout<<"Note length value cannot be less than 1 or more than 16, please re-enter";
return false; 
}
return true;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int CalculateNoteNumber(string tempName)
{
int Octave;
int Note;
tempName[0] = toupper(tempName[0]);
Octave = ((tempName[tempName.length()-1]) -48) * 12;
if (tempName.length() == 2)
{ 
if(tempName[0] == 'C')
{
return notenumber = 0;
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'D')
{
return notenumber = 2;
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'E') 
{
return notenumber = 4;
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'F') 
{
return notenumber = 5; 
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'G') 
{
return notenumber = 7;
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'A') 
{
return notenumber = 9; 
}
else
{
return notenumber = 11;
}
}
else if (tempName.length() == 3)
{ 
if(tempName[0] == 'C')
{
return notenumber = 1;
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'D')
{
return notenumber = 3;
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'F') 
{
return notenumber = 6; 
}
else if(tempName[0] == 'G') 
{
return notenumber = 8;
}
else
{
return notenumber = 10; 
}
}
int main();
{
noteStorage noteData[8];
//string note;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
cout<<"Please enter note: " << i << ": ";

while (1)
{
string tempName;
cin>>tempName;
int noteNumber = CalculateNoteNumber(tempName);
if (ValidateNote(tempName) == true)
{
noteData[i].noteName = tempName;
break;
}
else
{
cout << "Please enter correctly: ";
}
} //end first while
cout<<"Please enter note length: ";
while (1)
{
int tempLength;
cin>>tempLength;
if (ValidateNoteLength(tempLength) == true)
{
noteData[i].noteLength = tempLength;
break;
}
else
{
cout << "Please enter correctly: ";
}
}//end while 2
cout<<"Thank you\n";
} //end for
cout<<"Your note and note lengths are: "<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
cout<<noteData[i].noteName<<"Length: ";
cout<<noteData[i].noteLength<<endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

entered (with a value in milliseconds). Once the note names and note lengths have been entered, the console then converts the notenames to the corresponding midi numbers, and outputs said midi numbers, note length and note names back to the user.

I've been having the same problem for two days now; everytime I build the solution it comes back with the same error:

> "Fatal error C1075, end of file found before last brace '{' was
>   matched".

If anyone could point me the right way to solving this it would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Formatting your code properly should be of great help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a **}** at the end of `int CalculateNoteNumber(string tempName)`.
You will also have to remove the **;** after `int main()` for your program to compile.

If you would have formatted your code properly you could have fixed these errors on your own.

Comment: For some reason when I copy code from Visual Studio it puts it all in one line, inside VS it looks fine (to me, although i'm not practiced in code layout)

Comment: Can you recommend the best way to allow the user to enter a bass melody also? Not sure on how to do it other than copy and pasting the same code

Comment: @Hushhh no idea sorry, you should ask a new question